# true vs TRUE in Swift

Tags: swift, boolean

This might be a strange question but I´m not sure if I´m doing something wrong (or if it is a bug).
My problem is that Swift does´t let me write true in a BOOL statement.

For example, I´m trying to write the dismissViewControllerAnimated function like this:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

However, when I start writing it and get to the part where I have to write the flag (true), Swift suggests DYDL_BOOL TRUE. And It writes TRUE, not true.

If I delete TRUE and write instead true, the build fails. But if I write true elsewhere, copy and paste it, everything works as it should. Why is this happening? Why Swift doesn´t suggest true in the floating window? Maybe I have to configure something or I´m doing something wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: Xcode suggests the floating window, not Swift. It's a tool suggestion, not a language element. I'm not sure the tools are mature enough yet to say that they actually mean to imply that `TRUE` is preferable to `true` in Swift. They're probably just getting confused. This is a comment rather than an answer though because I'm speculating on things I don't know for certain.

Comment: True, I was thinking in Swift, but it´s Xcode who is suggesting TRUE and not true. The problem is it does´t allow me to write true as it gives an error.

Comment: What Beta version do you run?

Comment: I can use 'true' without problem in XCode 6.0 beta 6 on OSX maverick